PVOID and HINSTANCE
AFAIK HINSTANCE is defined through(ref: Microsoft document):
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
typedef HANDLE HINSTANCE;

But why I can't use PVOID when defining _tWinMain?
int WINAPI
_tWinMain (PVOID hInstance, PVOID hPrevInstance, PTSTR pCmdLine, int nShowCmd)

gcc says:
error: conflicting types for 'WinMain'; have 'int(void *, void *, CHAR *, int)' {aka 'int(void *, void *, char *, int)'}
   64 | _tWinMain (PVOID hInstance, PVOID hPrevInstance, PTSTR pCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
      | ^~~~~~~~~

mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winbase.h:1111:14: note: previous declaration of 'WinMain' with type 'int(struct HINSTANCE__ *, struct HINSTANCE__ *, CHAR *, int)' {aka 'int(struct 
HINSTANCE__ *, struct HINSTANCE__ *, char *, int)'}
 1111 |   int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd);
      |              ^~~~~~~

I'm using mingw from winlibs 11.2 in Windows 10(64 bit).
FYI, in my mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wtypes.h of winlibs:
typedef void *HINSTANCE;

Update:
Following @Retired Ninja's instruction, I disable the STRICT flag and it works(in mingw):
#define NO_STRICT

According to this message "mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winbase.h:1111:14: note: previous declaration of 'WinMain' with type 'int(struct HINSTANCE__ *, struct HINSTANCE__ *, CHAR *, int)' {aka 'int(struct
HINSTANCE__ *, struct HINSTANCE__ *, char *, int)'}" using void * instead of struct HINSTANCE__ * makes the function declarations incompatible.

Depends on if STRICT is enabled or not in Visual Studio, may be the same with MinGW. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/strict-type-checking That said, just because you can do something doesn't mean it is a good idea. Type names have meaning and show intent, even if they are just a typedef of something else.
